# How can I make an angular $scope property update itself in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

So currently, I can make my code display the information it gets from a json file by binding it to a $scope property called cities. I did this by setting it equal to an array in jquery called results. Displaying it the first time works perfectly. The problem is when I try to filter the results by picking on option on a select box. The array gets updated like it should in jquery, but it seems like the value of $scope.cities stays the same. Ideally, $scope.cities would be "refreshed" every time I call initMap in jquery.

---

I think scope.apply() is the solution to my problems, but it doesn't seem to help. I've also heard that using jquery with angular is a bad idea. Is there a way I could write the same function inside the controller/angular to fix this? When I tried to write it there, I couldn't use the google maps api functions. Maybe I have to inject them as dependencies?

---

```
<select name="Min Price" class="custom-select">
  <option>Min Price</option>
  <option>500+</option>
  <option>1750+</option>
  <option>2000+</option>
  <option>2500+</option>
</select>
<div data-ng-repeat="home in cities">
 <div class="results-homes" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultsModal">
  <span data-ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + home.picture + ')'}"></span>
   <div>
    <p>{{home.type}} <span class="pull-right">{{home.beds}} bds/{{home.baths}} ba/{{home.sqft}} sqft</span>
    </p>
    <p>{{home.price}}/mo<span class="pull-right">{{home.address}}</span></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### Heres the select box and the part that's supposed to be repeated for the list of results.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'app.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
  var minPrice = 0;
  $(".custom-select").on("change", function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    var targetValue = target.val();


    switch (target.attr("name")) {
      case "Min Price":
        if (targetValue !== "Min Price") {

          minPrice = parseFloat(targetValue);

        } else {
          minPrice = 0;
        }
        break;
        }
        initMap();
        });
        function initMap() {
    results = [];
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 45.397,
        lng: -70.644
      },
      zoom: 5
    });


    for (var i = 0; i < data.homes.length; i++) {
      var dataBeds = parseFloat(data.homes[i].beds);
      var dataBaths = parseFloat(data.homes[i].baths);
      var dataPrice = parseFloat(data.homes[i].price);
      var dataSqft = parseFloat(data.homes[i].sqft);
      var lat = data.homes[i].lat;
      var long = data.homes[i].long;
      var address = data.homes[i].address;
      var myLatLng = {
        lat: parseInt(data.homes[i].lat),
        lng: parseInt(data.homes[i].long)
      };


      if (minPrice <= dataPrice) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
        results.push(data.homes[i]);

      }
    }
  }
  initMap();
}
});
});
</script>
```

---

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('realEstateApp', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', "getResults", function ($scope,    getResults) {
 window.setTimeout(function () {
   $scope.cities = results;
   $scope.$apply("cities", results);
  }, 200);
}]);
</script>
```

Here's my angular code.

---

```
{

"homes": [
 {
  "address": "133 Parker street",
  "type": "apartment",
  "beds": "2",
  "baths": "4",
  "price": "2000",
  "city": "Miami",
  "state": "FL",
  "picture": "http://www.directcommercialfunding.com/images/apartment-building-loans.jpg",
  "sqft": "2000",
  "lat": "49.735495",
  "long": "-73.910745"
 },
 {
  "address": "857 17th street",
  "type": "apartment",
  "beds": "3",
  "baths": "2",
  "price": "800",
  "city": "Dallas",
  "state": "TX",
  "picture":  "http://i2.interiorim.com/uploads/original/201606/27/interiorim.com_future_light_Dream_house_lifestyle_11619.jpg",
  "sqft": "3000",
  "lat": "48.735496",
  "long": "-73.910746"
 }]}
```

### and here's the json file

Sorry if I included too much code, I also simplified certain parts of it to make it easier to read. Just to be clear, I want $scope.cities to update with var results. so if var results = [1,2,3], then $scope.cities = [1,2,3]. But if someone were to change the select box to make results = [4,5,6], $scope.cities would also change to [4,5,6].

Comment: lots of angular bad practices going on here. Get rid of jQuery in your app and use angular methodology. See [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Get familiar with all the event directives available in the docs api reference. Could be using `ng-change` here...and also use `$http` instead of `$.ajax`. Also learn about `ng-model` for binding scope model to forms controls